# How to get the position of a apply button in a html page in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, button, position

I have a apply button in a filter bar with several filters , sometimes this apply button will display in the next row instead of showing it in the same row with the other filters.How i can identify the position of this **apply button** in order to identify where it's displaying in the html page.

```
<div class="filter-container">
     <button (click)="apply() "
                    [ngClass]="{'a-btn--disabled': isDisable}" id ="apply"
                    mat-raised-button  >Apply
           </button>
</div>
```

Apply button and other filters are inside this `<div class="filter-container">`.This is my component code.

```
 const fpH = $('.apply').positionY;
 console.log(fpH);
```

But `console.log(fpH);` prints as `undefined`. I tried with `paddingRight` but it's also shows like `undefined`

what can i do for this

Answer (score 1):

`$('.apply')` searches for an element with class apply, looks like you are trying to find an element with **id** of class, if you want to use, the selector for that is `'#apply'`, so in your case, replace `$('.apply')` with `$('#apply')`

However, you should utilize Angular's [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) in order to do what you are looking for.

so your html will look like:

```
<div class="filter-container">
     <button #applyBtn (click)="apply() "
                    [ngClass]="{'a-btn--disabled': isDisable}" id ="apply"
                    mat-raised-button  >Apply
           </button>
</div>
```

in in your component:

```
@ViewChild('applyBtn') applyBtn: ElementRef;
```

When you want to access the element (in the component):

```
this.applyBtn.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()
```

which will give you the location and dimensions of your element

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-viewchild-with-bounding-rect?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: `this.applyBtn.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect()` is giving a `undefined` value